# When did iptables last restart?

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm troubleshooting a problem that I think's related to iptables on my centos 7 clients, and when they restart.

Is there any way to tell how long the current iptables policy has been 'active' for, as I think that's what's changed... but I'm not sure how I'd tell.

Answer (score 0):

If you type `service iptables status` it should show you the uptime of `iptables`. By default CentOS/RHEL 7 is running `firewalld` service.
If you want to swap to iptables, then you have to install it :

```
yum install iptables-services
systemctl mask firewalld
systemctl enable iptables
systemctl enable ip6tables
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl start iptables
systemctl start ip6tables
```

Then you can check the uptime with `service iptables status`. Here is a sample output :

```
service iptables status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  iptables.service
● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2016-11-28 15:56:29 UTC; 1min 19s ago
  Process: 2899 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2899 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/iptables.service
```

If you want to see when the process is accessing the config file, I ugess you can do it with `strace` and just filter the trace for the configuration path/filename.

Comment: does that show us the last time that new rules are loaded ?

Comment: yes, this command shows the uptime of the service in Centos/RHEL 7

Comment: uptime but not last change !!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using firewalld. Just iptables.

Comment: @Wissam If you change iptables rules in the config file, you have to reload iptables.

Comment: @Sobrique then type `service iptables status` , you should get among the details a line containing somethign like 'Active : active (running) since....do you have `iptables-services` installed and the service is enabled ?

Comment: @mazs and if i did `iptables-restore` ?

Comment: Then note down the time....`iptables-restore` won't reset the uptime counter of the service...but why would you use `iptables-restore` if you want to know  since when the rules are loaded ? running `service iptables restart` would provide you with this info if needed.

Comment: you can as well do `strace` the process and filter the access to the iptables config file